# Why is my app freezing when func is called

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, apple-m1

Whenever I call this function, my app freezes and nothing in the debug console prints. I am trying to get strings and a double from firebase and then stick them into an identifiable struct array. Any Ideas???

If you have another idea for storing that object, I would love to read it.

```
var count = Int()
var name = Array<String>()
var imageUrl = Array<String>()
var id = Array<String>()
var rating = Array<Double>()
var url = Array<String>()
var keys = 0
db.collection("parties").document(Utilities.code).addSnapshotListener { document, error in
    //check for error
    if error == nil {
        //check if document exists
        print("No error")
        if document != nil && document!.exists {
            print("Document Exists")
            if let array = document!.get("yesName") as? Array<String> {
                count = array.count
                name = array
                print("yesName = \(array)")
                keys += 1
            }
            if let array = document!.get("yesImg") as? Array<String> {
                imageUrl = array
                print("yesImg = \(array)")
                keys += 1
            }
            if let array = document!.get("yesId") as? Array<String> {
                id = array
                print("yesId = \(array)")
                keys += 1
            }
            if let array = document!.get("yesRating") as? Array<Double> {
                rating = array
                print("yesRating = \(array)")
                keys += 1
            }
            if let array = document!.get("yesUrl") as? Array<String> {
                url = array
                print("yesUrl = \(array)")
                keys += 1
            }
        }
    }else {
        print("error = \(error!)")
    }
}
while keys < 6 {
    if name.count > 0 && imageUrl.count > 0 && id.count > 0 && rating.count > 0 && url.count > 0 {
        for _ in 0...count {
            yes.list.append(RestaurantListViewModel(name: name.first!, imageUrl: URL(string: imageUrl.first!)!, id: id.first!, rating: rating.first!, url: url.first!))
            print("combined = \(yes.list.append(RestaurantListViewModel(name: name.first!, imageUrl: URL(string: imageUrl.first!)!, id: id.first!, rating: rating.first!, url: url.first!)))")
            name.removeFirst()
            imageUrl.removeFirst()
            id.removeFirst()
            rating.removeFirst()
            url.removeFirst()
        }
        keys = 6
    }
}
```

Comment: If your condition `if name.count > 0 && imageUrl.count > 0 && id.count > 0 && rating.count > 0 && url.count > 0` is never met, the `while` loop will last forever, essentially freezing your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snapshot listener will execute asynchronously that means in some time after the current method is finished. So the code after it is called is executed only once and just after listener creation : there is nothing yet in the arrays and keys == 0. May be this code should be inside the listener call after document is read and array updated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to debug `while keys < 6 {` circle?

Next line condition

```
if name.count > 0 && imageUrl.count > 0 && id.count > 0 && rating.count > 0 && url.count > 0
```

can easily equals to `false` and you get infinity circle running.

Also I see few logic issues in your code: in the first part of code you set up required fields (`keys` equals in a range from 0 to 6). But in the second part inside circle `while keys < 6` you require all 6 fields and want to exit only after all values will have `count > 0`. You need to get `value.count` only when it needed.

Comment: how would you wait until all the data is pulled before showing it?

Comment: Just notify your app when data was pulled.
For example you can create a function for this purpose.
`private func notify() { for _ in 0...count {...}
}`
and call this function when your data has been pulled and you're ready to show it.

Comment: How would that fix anything? I am just creating more code to do the same task in the same queue.